# How to remove trailing slash in folder URL without breaking index

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've read so many posts and tried to get my .htaccess file to work but without success.

Situation - I have an index.php file in a /watch directory that contains a dynamic video player. I want to make my URL look like this.

`//example.com/watch?v=Hghj12`

currently I have this...

`//example.com/watch/?v=Hghj12`

That trailing slash after the /watch/ folder needs to go. I want any link to example.com/watch/ to resolve to example.com/watch without breaking the page. Currently I get a 403 error.

My current `.htaccess` for the /watch folder:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to remove the trailing slash and using a `.htaccess` file within `/watch` then you could use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: Still getting a 403 error with example.com/watch and typing example.com/watch/ doesn't remove the slash.